# List output out of order python

Tags: python, list

I am using list in python program, following is the code

```
x = [['Port', 'Status']]
x.append({11,'Open'})
x.append({22,'Close'})
x.append({356,'Open'})
x.append({1024,'Close'})
x.append({512,'Open'})
x.append({777,'Close'})
print(x)
```

the output of above is

```
    [['Port', 'Status'], set([11, 'Open']), set(['Close', 22]), set(['Open', 356]), set([1024, 'Close'])
, set([512, 'Open']), set([777, 'Close'])]
```

Problem is that the output is not in the order It was entered. i.e on some cases string is appearing before integer vice versa on other cases. Please help.

Comment: From [\[Python\]: set definition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset): _A set object is an **unordered** collection of distinct hashable objects_. To keep the order use *list*s (as you do for the header - 1st element), or *tuple*s instead of *set*s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements

```
    for example:
    >> basket = {'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana'}
    >> print(basket)         # see that duplicates have been removed
    >> {'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'apple'}

you can see that order has changed.
```

You are appending {11,'Open'} which is set and can change order at run time. so better use ordered data structure if you want to maintain the order.

```
for example use like this:
>> x.append((11, 'Open'))
or 
>> x.append([11, 'Open'])
```

Answer (score 1):

set is an unordered, you can use `tuple`  or `list` instead:

```
x = [['Port', 'Status']]
x.append((11,'Open'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [] instead of {} as jyotish implied.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a set as a container for the values, which do not have a fixed order.

Instead, you can use a tuple (e.g. `(11, 'Open')`) or another list (e.g. `[11, 'Open']`). But a tuple is probably a better match here.